# Sidebar widget overlaps moderator message thread

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

When viewing a moderator message thread, the sidebar widget may overlap the messages. Here is an example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: While this should definitely be addressed by SE, the following CSS is a hack which should patch over the issue:`/* CM escalations, mod messages, etc.. Confines entries to the width of the #mainbar container. */ body:is(.mod-page, .user-page) #content #mainbar > table.clear:not([id]), body:is(.mod-page, .user-page) #content #mainbar > table.clear:not([id]) > tbody, body:is(.mod-page, .user-page) #content #mainbar > table.clear:not([id]) > tbody > tr, body:is(.mod-page, .user-page) #content #mainbar > table.clear:not([id]) > tbody > tr > td:first-child:last-child { display: block; width: 100%;}`

Comment: Did it do this before you got the response with the code block? We currently have a bug we're poking at that is caused by code blocks (and images, I think) causing the main div to stretch. At least as far as the code version of the bug goes, it was raised on the Mod Team but I'll add this to the ticket as a place to poke at and respond if we do end up solving the issue.

Comment: @Catija yes, if I remove the reply with the code block (it's the one that activates Shog9's user script) the overlap is gone. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/admin/cm-message/104#104) is a link you can use for testing.